# What is the method of moment estimate and MLE in this case?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

For a given distribution, I have a restriction on the parameter space of $\theta$ which says that $\theta>0$.
Now, the method of moment estimate of $\theta$ is $\frac{1-2\overline{X}}{\overline{X}-1}$ and the MLE of $\theta$ is $-1-\frac{n}{\sum_{i}^{n}{ln x_i}}$ where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the observed values of a sample of size $n$.
For a given observed sample from the distribution involved here, if I calculate the method of moment estimate to be negative, and the MLE to be negative, then what does that mean? Would the MLE be $0+$? And I don’t understand the interpretation of a method of moment estimate that comes out to be negative.

Comment: Is this useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057429/about-method-of-moments-and-maximum-likelihood/4057439#4057439

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. Thank you.